# Windows Server 2012 - Require credentials only on file/folder access?

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, credentials

To avoid configuring multiple user accounts on clients (Windows 7 & 8), could it be possible to configure Windows Server 2012 and clients in a way that the credentials are prompted only when a user attempts to open a shared folder/file?

Comment: Per default it should ask for credentials every time you connect to a shared folder, unless you tell it to store the credentials.

Comment: So for example, if the computer is not part of a domain, it will not require credentials on boot/local login. Then once a user attempts to connect to a shared resource, the server would require credentials. What if the client requests a second access to shared resources within the working session. Would it be required to enter credentials on each folder access?

Comment: Ah I see. No they are cached, but have you tried this? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852185%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396